# Карта облаков за последнее время

Tags: поиск-api, weather

Подскажите сервисы, разумеется, что погодные, для получения карты облаков или хотя бы ее тайлов.

Удалось найти http://www.weather.com/weather/map/interactive/l/UPXX0844:1:UP?layers=sat&zoom=1&baseMap=h

С индексами тайлов понятно, они считаются с левого нижнего угла, а не верхнего - как это чаще всего бывает, но вот недостаток: тайлов нету для мест, которые ближе к полюcам, и это где-то 30-40% широты

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё [SAT24](http://sat24.com/?ir=true).

Покрытие весьма неплохое, но навигация по сайту ужасная.

И есть ещё [NASA Langley Cloud and Radiation Research](http://www-pm.larc.nasa.gov/).

По-поводу высоких широт... Не думаю что спутники ДЗЗ активно снимают эту область, приполярные области (особенно северного полюса) практически не снимают.

Comment: еще основное то, что нужно получить сами слои облаков с альфа каналом

Comment: Ммм... Я сомневаюсь что такое есть с хорошим покрытием...

Answer (score 0):

http://meteocenter.net/fact/fact_cl.png - низкая облачность
http://meteocenter.net/fact/fact_c.png - общая облачность

Comment: не то, нужно фотореалистичное